# Can I back up the saved WiFi passwords on my Mac?

Tags: macos, wifi, settings

Too frequently my Mac connects to WiFi but can’t access the Internet on cafes (my iPhone works properly). It has been tormenting me for over a year and I tried everything I found on the web but still could not resolve it. So I finally want to reset the WiFi settings.

However, if I reset the WiFi settings on my Mac, it erases all the saved WiFi passwords I connected on cafes, which have more than 500. It is not what I want to do to ask each password again whenever I enter the cafes again, so I rather want to back it up and restore whenever I want.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot Keychain Access]

All WiFi passwords are stored in Keychain.
So you need to make a backup of the keychain folder.

Location:

```
~/Library/Keychains/
```